# error caused by undefined symbol: glXGetProcAddress

Tags: debian, xorg, system-installation

After my last dist-upgrade of my testing debian system, X refuses to start. I can see the following error (which shows up when gnome-session is started):

> symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2: undefined
>   symbol: glXGetProcAddress

Besides, even texlive refuses to upgrade, with the same error (caused by luatex).

I don't know how to fix this issue: is it possibile that one crucial library is missing? If not, what else could cause this problem?

Comment: maybe the **dist**-upgrade removed your graphic driver and/or the relative glx implementation

Comment: I am trying to find the package removed, but with no success...

Comment: What is your video card? Even if you found it probably you have to downgrade the xorg-server to install it again.

Comment: What version of the `libcairo2` package do you have, and of its dependencies `libgl1` or `libgl1-mesa-swx11` and `libegl1-mesa`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@peterph's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93736/34446) was very close to the problem.

The video card was a Matrox G550 (mga) but in the past there been an nvidia installed and some glx stuff remained in `/usr/lib/tls`.

I've not experience with the mga driver but my understanding is that there's not a proprietary glx implementation, so we gone ahead trying to get the mesa working.

Once installed `libgl1-mesa-glx` and `glx-alternative-mesa` we checked the `libcairo` with `ldd`, then used `dpkg -S` with full path to understand from which packages were picked the `libGL` and `libGLcore` resolved by `ldd`, just to check that was mesa, both the libraries weren't in any package.

Moved those libraries away and this time `ldd` shown the right mesa libraries were used, at this point I asked @zar to check again and his answer been that this time `apt-get -f install` finished properly and `gdm3` run without errors.

Even being a bug I think we can't fill any bug request as the non debianized nvidia driver broken the *contract*.

Proprietary drivers installation are still *evil*, I don't understand why they favor their own crap `supposed-to-install-everywhere.run` instead of looking for some collaboration effort at least with major distros (that probably would come for free/no charge).

Answer (score 1):

The error means, that your Cairo installation is missing run-time link dependency - judging by the symbol name it's an OpenGL implementation package (maybe Mesa) that is missing/corrupted. Reinstalling Cairo could help, provided the package manager fixes package dependencies, which are probably the cause of the error, and installs all the missing prerequisites.

You may also run `ldd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2` and check for lines containing `=> not found` - that will tell you what library is missing on your system, search which package contains it and (re)install it.

This is also a typical syndrome for situations where the depending packages are updated without updating their dependencies (that can easily happen for example with proprietary drivers - which turned out to be the case here).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that command, but I have no lines "=> not found".

Comment: the symbol is in `libGL`, which is also provided by `libgl1-mesa-glx` as a software only (not hw accelerated) implementation, an `update-alternatives` maybe required

Comment: I have libgl1-mesa-glx installed, I have tried to redownload it and reinstall, but still with no result. How should I use update-alternatives?

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config glx`

Comment: Uh, error, no alternatives for glx

Comment: try install `glx-alternative-mesa`

Comment: Done, but I still have the same error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10908/discussion-between-alex-and-zar)

Comment: Ok, problem solved, thanks to Alex. I had an old installation of proprietary nvidia driver, contained in /usr/lib/tls. I have removed it, and now libcairo loads the correct libGL library.

Comment: Excellent. @Alex I didn't want to interrupt your "latin" :) yesterday, but you might want to put that into a separate answer to get some credit for the effort (thanks for taking over, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

In RH nomenclature: (I don't know Debian Packaging Format as well)

I tried, and found the following:

1. `# sudo **'yum whatprovides /usr/lib/libGL.so.1'**` yields:

   ```
   *mesa-libGL-9.2.5-1.20131220.fc20.i686 : Mesa libGL runtime libraries and DRI drivers*
   ```

   A. `ldd` prints *shared object library dependencies*, so it is not the tool for the job UNLESS there is a problem with the linking. I didn't find anything.

I looked **REALLY HARD** and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514745/how-do-i-view-the-list-of-functions-a-linux-shared-library-is-exporting)

2. The rest was easy:

```
    # nm -D /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 |grep 'glXGetProcAddress'
    00014310 T glXGetProcAddress
    00014310 T glXGetProcAddressARB
```

3. I got **Adobe Reader** to run after this.

Answer (score -1):

`Gnome` are written according to `GTK+ library` and it depend on `cairo`  library, your `cairo library` occurpted when you upgrade, please `re-install` it, not from local , please again download it.use `apt-cache` and search for every `cairo packages`

Comment: It doesn't work... I have redownload and reinstalled all the *cairo* packages, but I still have the same error.

Comment: please bug report..!

Comment: I dont' know how to do it... Is there a Correct Debian Way? I think that I have something broken on my system --- but I don't know how to find it...

Comment: My understanding is that isn't a bug, when the xorg-server upgrade its ABI version and the installed drivers aren't compatible anymore they are removed (and you agree by saying Yes at the dist-upgrade). Instead you should wait to dist-upgrade when your new driver (which support the new xorg) is debianized.